# PyODBC: /tmp/odbc.log file exceeds more than 90GB and stops data fetching from Data Warehouse

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to fetch 150 million rows with messages data from data warehouse into my EC2 instance. I have 90GB available space on my disk. When I put my query for running, following is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 964, in fetchall
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchall_impl())
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 915, in _fetchall_impl
    return self.cursor.fetchall()
pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLFetch)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "en_str.py", line 45, in <module>
    INNER JOIN notified.Message m ON c.MessageID = m.MessageID where c.CreateDate>'2016-01-01 00:00:00.0';''',db007_cnxn)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 331, in read_sql_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1092, in read_query
    data = result.fetchall()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 970, in fetchall
    self.cursor, self.context)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 185, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 964, in fetchall
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchall_impl())
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 915, in _fetchall_impl
    return self.cursor.fetchall()
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLFetch)')
```

My disk space gets full and odbc.log file in tmp folder is taking 90GB space. I have another mounted disk with 100TB space but odbc.log is generated only in tmp folder. What is the solution for this? Any thoughts on how this problem can be solved? Alternatively, how can I change odbc.log file location from 100 GB space disk to the disk with 100 TB space?

Also, instead of giving ec2 instance location, if I give s3 bucket location, will that avoid this odbc.log file?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have verbose FreeTDS logging on. Most of the time, the config file is located in `/etc/freetds.conf` or `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`.

You'll want to look for `dump file` in the FreeTDS log. Also, check `odbcinst.ini`, as logging can be turned on there.

You'll probably find one of the various logging facilities pointing to `/tmp/odbc.log` and that'll be your culprit. Good luck!